# SQL materialized path or is there an easier way?

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, hierarchy

Okay this problem will be a little hard to explain but here it goes..

I have a query that pulls in data that is rendered in a tree like visualization.  The yloc calculated in this query is used to determine the y location to render certain objects attached to these capabilities at.

Just using the MAX(coalesce(CAP_TREE2.depth),0) doesn't work. So I wrote an algorithm that shows what I need yloc in certain situations.

Here is the algorithm:

```
    if (capability has c2 !=1)
    {
        yloc = 0
    }
    else if (capability is child (at any depth) of capability with c2 != 1)
    {
        yloc = depth - (depth of first parent with c2 != 1)
    }
    else
    {
        y = depth
    }
```

**NOTE:** c2 represents the childNumber (in alphabetical order). So if a capability has two children "A" and "B". "A" will have c2 = 1 and "B" will have c2 = 2.

I have had a LOT of trouble trying to implement this algorithm in SQL (Oracle 11g R2).
The issue I'm having trouble finishing is the **else if** clause in my algorithm.
I have been able to get all of the capabilities that are children (at any depth) of a capability with c2 != 1.

However, the part I haven't been able to finish is the 
**yloc = depth - (depth of first parent with c2 !=1)**

Can anyone PLEASE show me how to get the "depth of the first parent with c2 !=1" ?
My query would finally be complete if I can get that value.

I will show what values I expect from my sample data for this to try and make it more clear.

"Investment Management" first parent with c2 != 1 is "FPP" which has a depth of 2.
"3rd party Product Management" first parent with c2 != 1 is "FPP" which has a depth of 2.
"Order Management (PI)" first parent with c2 != 1 is "Operations and Services (PI)" with a depth of 2.

Note: Sorry I cannot change the schema.

Here is what I have so far..the bottom select statement is where I am working.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55b5a/116

Schema SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE capability 
    (
     id int,
     parent_id int,
     name varchar(200)
    )
;

CREATE TABLE tree
  (
     descendantid int,
     ancestorid int,
     depth int
  )
;

INSERT INTO capability (id, parent_id, name) VALUES (1, -1, 'BU-Specific Capabilities');
INSERT INTO capability (id, parent_id, name) VALUES (2, 1, 'PI Capability Model');
INSERT INTO capability (id, parent_id, name) VALUES (3, 2, 'Core Business Processing (PI)');
INSERT INTO capability (id, parent_id, name) VALUES (4, 3, 'Institutional Trust Administration (PI)');
INSERT INTO capability (id, parent_id, name) VALUES (5, 2, 'FPP');
INSERT INTO capability (id, parent_id, name) VALUES (6, 5, 'Investment Management');
INSERT INTO capability (id, parent_id, name) VALUES (7, 6, '3rd party Product Management');
INSERT INTO capability (id, parent_id, name) VALUES (8, 2, 'Operations and Shared Services (PI)');
INSERT INTO capability (id, parent_id, name) VALUES (9, 8, 'Order Management (PI)');
INSERT INTO capability (id, parent_id, name) VALUES (10, 8, 'Settlements (PI)');
INSERT INTO capability (id, parent_id, name) VALUES (11, -1, 'Common Core Capabilities');

INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (1, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (2, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (2, 2, 0);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (3, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (3, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (3, 3, 0);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (4, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (4, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (4, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (4, 4, 0);                                               
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (5, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (5, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (5, 5, 0);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (6, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (6, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (6, 5, 1);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (6, 6, 0);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (7, 1, 4);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (7, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (7, 5, 2);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (7, 6, 1);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (7, 7, 0);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (8, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (8, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (8, 8, 0);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (9, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (9, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (9, 8, 1);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (9, 9, 0);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (10, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (10, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (10, 8, 1);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (10, 10, 0);
INSERT INTO tree (descendantid, ancestorid, depth) VALUES (11, 11, 0);
```

Query SQL:

```
SELECT
  cap.name,
  max(coalesce(CAP_TREE2.depth,0)) as ydepth,

  CASE
    WHEN cap.parent_id != -1
       THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cap.parent_id ORDER BY cap.name) --child number
    ELSE
       1
  END as c2

FROM capability cap
    INNER JOIN tree CAP_TREE2 ON CAP.id = CAP_TREE2.descendantid

group by cap.name, cap.id, cap.parent_id
;


  WITH ids(id, c2) AS ( -- Find the ids and the ranks
  SELECT
    id, 
    CASE
    WHEN parent_id = -1
      THEN 1
    ELSE
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY name) --child number
    END as c2
  FROM capability
),
t(id, depth) AS (
    SELECT id, 0 AS depth FROM ids WHERE c2 != 1  -- Take only ranks not equal to one
UNION ALL
    SELECT c.id, depth+1 FROM capability c JOIN t ON (c.parent_id = t.id)  -- Tree-walking
)
--SELECT DISTINCT cap.name, t.depth
--SELECT DISTINCT cap.name, min(t.depth)
--FROM capability cap JOIN t USING(id)
--group by cap.name


SELECT
  cap.name,
  CASE

    -- cap has childNumber != 1
    WHEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cap.parent_id ORDER BY cap.name) != 1
      THEN 0 -- y = 0

    -- cap is child of cap with childNumber != 1
    WHEN cap.name IN (SELECT DISTINCT capa.name
                      FROM capability capa
                      JOIN t USING(id))
         THEN max(coalesce(CAP_TREE2.depth,0)) -- y = depth - (depth of first parent with childNumber != 1)

    ELSE max(coalesce(CAP_TREE2.depth,0)) -- y = depth 

  END as yloc


FROM capability cap
    INNER JOIN tree CAP_TREE2 ON CAP.id = CAP_TREE2.descendantid

group by cap.name,
         cap.id,
         cap.parent_id
```

Also, here is my desired resultset

```
NAME                                            DEPTH               C2            YLOC

BU-Specific Capabilities                          0                 1               0       --yloc=depth
Common Core Capabilities                          0                 1               0       --yloc=depth
PI Capability Model                               1                 1               1       --yloc=depth
Core Business Processing (PI)                     2                 1               2       --yloc=depth
FPP                                               2                 2               0       --yloc=0
Operations and Shared Services (PI)               2                 3               0       --yloc=0
Institutional Trust Administration (PI)           3                 1               3       --yloc=depth
Investment Management                             3                 1               1       --yloc=depth - (depth of FPP)
3rd party Product Management                      4                 1               2       --yloc=depth - (depth of FPP)
Order Management (PI)                             3                 1               1       --yloc=depth -(depth of Operations and..)
Settlements (PI)                                  3                 2               0       --yloc=0
```

Comment: Not a complete answer here, but I think you might consider two stages of processing - 1) transform your data into an appropriate data warehouse/reporting format, with depth info or other helpful fields, 2) report against that instead [i.e. different queries, different tables, etc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need the **tree** table, because you declared the relation from parent to child already in the **capability** table.

When you use the **CONNECT BY PRIOR** command from oracle it builds you the tree, and allows you determine the depth of the node with the **LEVEL** pseudo-column.

The only tricky part is to get the first parent node that has a depth > 1. As far as i understood your question this should be c2. The result is in the column 
**FIRST_PARENT_IN_DEPTH_G_1**.

```
SELECT ID
    , PARENT_ID
    , NAME
    , DEPTH
    , NODES_PER_LEVEL
    , TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ID_PATH, LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(ID_PATH, '^\s\d{1,}\s')) + 1, 
            INSTR(SUBSTR(ID_PATH, LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(ID_PATH, '^\s\d{1,}\s')) + 1), ' '))) 
            AS FIRST_PARENT_IN_DEPTH_G_1
FROM (
    SELECT ID
        , PARENT_ID
        , NAME
        , LEVEL DEPTH
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PARENT_ID, LEVEL) NODES_PER_LEVEL
        , sys_connect_by_path( id, ' ' ) ID_PATH
    FROM capability 
    START WITH PARENT_ID = -1
    CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = PARENT_ID
    )    
ORDER BY ID_PATH
```